# Parcel - Babel - Vue - Error: Cannot find module `.../.../img.svg`

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, parcel, parceljs

Im a bit in the dark therefore reaching out as I couldnt find a solution or answer. Im using parcel with Vue and trying to import a static image as `../img/logo.svg`. This used to work before until I introduced Babel to the mix. Now I get `Error: Cannot find module 'img/logo.svg'` during runtime. It is weird because in the dist folder I see a logo.svg with a hash. Is it a babel or parcel issue? do I need some extra plugin? or something Im missing?.

Im basically using babel out the box. I just have in my `.babelrc`

```
{
 "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

The file structure goes like this, Im trying to reference `logo.svg` from `Page.vue` as `import logo from '../img/logo.svg';`

```
src
 ┣ components
 ┃ ┣ Component.vue
 ┣ css
 ┃ ┗ css.css
 ┣ img
 ┃ ┣ logo.svg
 ┃ 
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┗ Page.vue
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ main.js
.babelrc
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Could you post your file structure and the file where the image is being imported into? I think it's a problem with your relative path. Your question title says `…/…/img.svg` and you are using `../img/logo.svg`

Comment: @Tony I updated the structure! The .../.../ was just for representation.

Comment: It seems to be a common problem with Parcel. According to this [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/879), the error may originate from importing an image multiple times in the file.This could be in the template, style(background-image) or script(import 'image' from ....`). This [comment](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/879#issuecomment-395527181) proffers a solution. Check it out to see if it helps you.

Comment: @Tony Thank you!, unfortunately I do not see any difference, I tried using `require` as well.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-v1-10-0-babel-7-flow-elm-and-more-c20736553573) states that you may not need a .babelrc file. This is what the article states  `For many Parcel projects, a .babelrc is not needed at all since Parcel automatically supports compiling modern JS out of the box with babel-preset-env, along with automatic JSX support, and now Flow as well (see below). For those projects, you don’t need to do anything at all to start using Babel 7 — Parcel will do it for you automatically!` I don't know how reliable it is, but it's worth checking out.