# Vue - Parcel Cannot Find Module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parcel

I'm trying to import an image in vue using parcel :

`import logo from '../img/logo.svg';` from `Page.vue`.

Paths are correct.

The error is always the same : `cannot find module ../img/logo.svg`.

In the dist folder I can see the images hashed.

Im loosing my mind :(

```
src
 ┣ components
 ┃ ┣ Component.vue
 ┣ css
 ┃ ┗ css.css
 ┣ img
 ┃ ┣ logo.svg
 ┃ 
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┗ Page.vue
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ main.js
.babelrc
```

Comment: Why you want to import this image ?

Comment: @Namysh because I want to do some dynamic stuff, i.e: logo: variable ? logo : logo2

Comment: I don't think you can import an image like this, you should use the `Image` object with the source of you image. Like `const logo = new Image(); logo.src = "url"`

Comment: @Namysh pretty sure you can, similar as in React https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html

Comment: Ok my bad I can't help you there, sorry and good luck (have you tried absolute path ?)

Comment: I am sorry to see that you are still struggling with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226633/parcel-babel-vue-error-cannot-find-module-img-svg#comment111809703_63226633), @Ehs. What has changed from then till now? Are you still using babel?

Comment: @Tony not much still using it, I think it is a parcel issue but no luck finding anything, I think I will give up and move to vue-cli or rollup or webpack or anything else :(

Comment: Hi, @Ehs, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58712521/7499991) help you?